# Is there any alternate way to write this query plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to write this code in one select query without if statement, because its looks like i'm repeating the code.
Any idea?

```
    if p_code is null then
      select *
        into v_row
        from group_matrix gm
       where gm.group_code= p_group_code
         and gm.code is null;
    else
      select *
        into v_row
        from group_matrix gm
       where gm.group_code= p_group_code
         and gm.code = p_code ;
    end if;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most readable way is with some boolean logic:

```
  select *
    into v_row
    from group_matrix gm
   where gm.group_code= p_group_code
     and ( (p_code is null and gm.code is null)
           or
           (p_code is not null and gm.code = p_code)
         )
```

This can be re-written in different more compact ways, but this one is quite self explaining.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to create the condition to check `p_code` and `gm.code`, both are null or both are same as follows:

```
select *
    into v_row
    from group_matrix gm
   where gm.group_code= p_group_code
     and ( (p_code is null and gm.code is null)
            or gm.code = p_code )
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks as

```
select *
into v_row
from group_matrix gm
where gm.group_code = p_group_code
  and (gm.code = p.code or p_code is null);
```

Comment: How will it check for null `gm.code` when `p_code` is null?

Answer (score 1):

you can use dynamic query  as well
if  p_code is null then
abc:=' gm.code is null'
else
abc:=' gm.code = p_code'
end if

vsql :=   'select * into v_rowfrom group_matrix gm where gm.group_code= p_group_code and'||abc;

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
into v_row
 from group_matrix gm 
where gm.group_code = p_group_code
  and decode(p_code, gm.code, 1, 2) = 1
```